# How to compile c#/c++ files from Java Application

Tags: c#, java, c++, compiler-construction

I am just looking into compilers and I was wondering is it possible to compile both c# and c++ files from a Java Application (e.g. to compile java from a java application you can use the JavaCompiler API). I have looked online for this but all i can find is ways to compile java files from c# and c++ and not the other way around.

If so, what API's can you use for this?

Comment: invoke the command line compiler for each language ?

Comment: ya i want to avoid using the command line compiler if i can

Comment: @HipHipArray And why would you want to avoid it?  It's almost certainly going to be easier than some sort of interop.

Comment: Just so that I can look at the code and try understand it really. As I am just starting my career as a programmer I would like to learn as much as possible so I would like to know the details of how these work and learn by trail and error

Comment: @HipHipArray And what do you expect to learn from this without using the command line compiler that the command line couldn't teach you?

Comment: I don't think this is possible and anyway, it's useless. The compilers are there for this.

Comment: @HipHipArray Are you expecting to be able to compile the entire thing yourself, without using any existing compiler?  If so...good luck.  You *might* be able to finish it before you die (although you won't be keeping up with the versions of the language that come out between now and then).

Comment: @Servy No, sorry if I have lead you to misunderstand my question. I want to use existing compilers, they are what I want to study. I want to know the different compilers out there to compile c# and c++ and study these and learn how to implement these using Java

Comment: @HipHipArray There are two main compilers for C# mono (for linux systems) and the one that microsoft distributes.  Since it's not implemented in Java, there won't really be much for you to learn beyond just calling csc.exe (which you can automate from within a Java app).

Comment: @HipHipArray - What you want to use is the command line compilers.  You do understand this is how Visual Studio for instance builds your code?  Why are you recreating something that already exists?  It seems you have awhile to go because at this point your barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @Servy: cheers for the help, will look have a look at this

Comment: @Ramhound: well it is a good thing so that i asked this so :) will start looking more at command line compilers and learning about these... cheers for the help

Comment: @HipHipArray, "implement these using Java" as in "I want to implement my own compiler for language in Java" or as in "how to call different tools from my Java program"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I want to call different tools from my Java program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the system commands for compiling and executing .cpp files(don't know much about c#) you might want to check out [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8). It details how to execute system commands from a Java program. Pass the system commands for compiling the required file in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does require knowing and managing all of the explicit build information in the Java code, which is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Consider learning how to call ant from Java code and using something like [this ant enhancement](http://codemesh.com/products/junction/doc/ant_cpp.html).

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about this product, but found it by searching for "can ant build c++?"

Answer (score 0):

For C# in Windows: compiler (csc.exe) is part of .Net install on Windows and can be found at well known location (like `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5` for .Net 3.5). The same place also contains MSBuild.exe that can build project files (*.csproj).

Your code may need to provide locations for referenced libraries if using Csc.exe to compile individual files.